# .htaccess Rewrite sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change my .htaccess so that when i go to http://example.com/foo it re-rewrites it to my_folder, currently if i go to http://example.com/ it re-writes to my_folder.

i have tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /foo$` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /foo` to the condition list but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_folder/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?foo/(.*)$ /my_folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: that only works for http://example.com/foo if i got to http://example.com/foo/bar it dosent work :(

Comment: @user2834482 your question just said "foo", if that's not it, then what is it? "foo" and all directories? If "foo" is anything, then the rules you have should do what you want

Comment: oh sorry, currently it forwards everything after foo so eg example.com/this/dir -re-writes to ---> my_folder/this/dir so i need example.com/foo/this/dir to re-write to ---> my_folder/this/dir

Comment: @user2834482 You need to have it **before** the rules that you already have